# Python Plotly Multi-Box Plot Additional Formatting

Tags: python, plotly

Looking to annotate a plotly multi-box plot show which datapoints have a value of `True` for column `"is_fail"`. Ie. add a red-circle around x, y datapoints where `df["is_fail"] == True`

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    "x": random.choices(range(1, 6), k=100),
    "y": random.choices(np.linspace(0, 12, num=1000), k=100),
    "group": random.choices(list(map(chr, range(65, 71))), k=100),
    "is_fail": random.choices([True, False], k=100),
    "points": "all",
  }
)
fig = px.box(df, x="x", y="y", color="group")
# code to annotate all df["is_fail"] == True
fig.show()
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Could you share a concept picture?

Comment: Hey @SanguineL, thanks for taking a look! It's hard to share a concept picture, because `"is_fail"` is randomly generated, however, imagine all points ("x", "y") where column value for "is_fail" is `True` would be circled in a thick red.

Comment: I think I'm making some headway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can be achieved with plotly's built-in `add_shape` method.**

---

Note, this is probably not the most elegant solution. I just problem-solved this without really caring about efficiency or runtime. Also, all of this code runs in place of where your comment, `# code to annotate ...`, was located

First, isolate the DataFrame Points that have `is_fail = True`. This can be achieved with `DataFrame.drop()`, which removes all points that pass a condition.

```
df.drop(df[df.is_fail == False].index, inplace=True)
```

(You could also skip that line entirely and highlight every point, but that's not what you were asking for.) Next is the somewhat complicated part of organizing the information in order to visualize it. Since the graph has multiple boxplots on the same `x` value, we must distinguish by groups and change their x values accordingly.

```
groups = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['group'] not in groups:
        groups.append(row['group'])
    if len(groups) == 6:
        break
```

Next, we change the x value for each point based on its group. Note that we have two values returning, since we must define the dimensions of a circle. The center of the circle would be the mean of the two returned values.

```
def get_plus_minus_x(x, group):
    global groups
    v = (groups.index(group) - 2.5) * .115
    return (x + v) - .025, (x + v) + .025
```

I more-or-less pulled these values out of my head and did some testing, but they seemed to do the trick on my computer.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    minus_x, plus_x = get_plus_minus_x(row['x'], row['group'])

    fig.add_shape(type="circle",
        xref="x", yref="y",
        x0=minus_x, y0=row['y']-.2, x1=plus_x, y1=row['y']+.2,
        line_color="Red",
    )
```

---

***Final Result***
[image: Final Result]

---

*Final Code*

```
df.drop(df[df.is_fail == False].index, inplace=True)

groups = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['group'] not in groups:
        groups.append(row['group'])
    if len(groups) == 6:
        break

def get_plus_minus_x(x, group):
    global groups

    v = (groups.index(group) - 2.5) * .115
    
    return (x + v) - .025, (x + v) + .025

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    
    minus_x, plus_x = get_plus_minus_x(row['x'], row['group'])
    
    fig.add_shape(type="circle",
        xref="x", yref="y",
        x0=minus_x, y0=row['y']-.2, x1=plus_x, y1=row['y']+.2,
        line_color="Red",
    )
```

---

**I hope this was what you were looking for!**

Comment: This is great, thank you! The `add_shape()` was the magic I was looking for :)